# NMEA data received but empty. Is there any secret?

Tags: windows, mobile, gps, serial-port, nmea

I have a tablet "Futjitsu Stylistic Q550". It's running on Windows 7 (not Phone!). It has a built-in GPS-receiver "Sierra Wireless". I need to parse NMEA data from COM-port. I can do it but it's always empty! Like "$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53". I've tried standing on open space a long time (so my Android device had located me via GPS for a long time) but NMEA data still empty. So I suppose that GPS is off. But I don't know how to figure it out. I've tried send to COM port $PARAM,START,0*61 but no changes. I've tried to insert SIM-card into the device, as it was suggested on one forum but result was the same. Well is it possible that GPS is idle or something or it's just not working? And if it is idle or off how can I enable it?

And.. That looks strange but GSV enumerates satellites but everyone of them has still no data e.g.: $GPGSV,4,1,16,32,,,,11,,,,23,,,*78

Comment: Same problem here, I get so many strings from GPS Nmea listener, but the GPRMC is always empty liker yours. Is there any requirement to get full data on GPRMC? Keep moving the device (walking, by car...)? I've test many minutes listening GPs but on the same position. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive $GPGSV,4,1,16,32,,,,11,,,,23,,,*78

Then your communication is ok, Gps is enabled.

You simply have to wait longer.
The first time GPS make a cold start may need 15 or more minutes.
The Sierra Gps, together with the Fujitsu Tablet is not very sensitive, but it works:

Put the Fujitsu on the roof of your car (not inside) and wait.
Inside some cars e.g Elektro Mobiles, my Fujitsu Tablet had problems with GPS signal.